# update statement breaking the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to figure out what's wrong here, but really not sure. I have a site with users, when a user edits details, it seems to override all other records with those details. This doesn't happen always but sometimes (of course the result is chaos!). Here is the code of update

```
public function update_edit()
    {
            /* echo " //// INSIDE UPDATE EDIT "; */

             $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'الاسم الكامل', 'isset|required|min_length[6]|max_length[100]');

                //check that there are no form validation errors
                if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {   
                    /* echo " //// INSIDE FORM VALIDATION"; */
                    if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
                    {
                                            /* echo " //// INSIDE SESSION VALIDATION"; */
                        $data = array();
                        $data = $this->profileModel->load_user_editable_data($this->session->userdata('username'));
                        $this->load->view('layout/header');
                        $this->load->view('profile_edit', $data);
                        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
                        //$this->load->view('thankyou');
                    }else{
                        //$this->load->view('login');
                        $this->login();
                    }
                }else{
                    $complete = $this->profileModel->update_profile($this->session->userdata('username')); 
                    if($complete == 1)
                    {       
                        $this->load->view('layout/header');
                        $this->load->view('update_complete');
                        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
                    }
                }

    }
```

This is the model code:

```
public function update_profile($username)
    {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $fullImagePath;
        if (isset($_FILES['profilepic']) && !empty($_FILES['profilepic']['name']))
        {
          if ($this->upload->do_upload('profilepic'))
          {
            $upload_data    = $this->upload->data();
            $fullImagePath = '/uploads/' . $upload_data['file_name']; 
           }
        }else{
            $fullImagePath = $this->session->userdata('profilepic');
        }
            $data = array(
                   'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                   'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                   'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                   'telephone' => $this->input->post('telephone'),
                   'about' => $this->input->post('about'),
                   'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                   'profilepic' => $fullImagePath,
                );

            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->update('free_user_members', $data); 

        return 1;
    }
```

and this is the form:

```
<div class="content_container">


    <div id="rt-main" class="mb8-sa4">
      <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="rt-grid-12">

        <div dir="rtl" class="homecontent">



            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('profile/update_edit'); ?>

            <? $this->session->set_userdata('profilepic', $profilepic); ?>

            <h5>الاسم الكامل</h5>
            <? $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'fullname',
                          'id'          => 'round_input',
                          'value'       => $fullname,
                        );

            echo form_input($data); ?>


            <h5>الايميل</h5>

            <? $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'email',
                          'id'          => 'round_input',
                          'value'       => $email,
                          'size' => '70'
                        );

            echo form_input($data); ?>

            <h5>الجوال</h5>
            <? $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'mobile',
                          'id'          => 'round_input',
                          'value'       => $mobile,
                        );

            echo form_input($data); ?>

            <h5>هاتف</h5>
            <? $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'telephone',
                          'id'          => 'round_input',
                          'value'       => $telephone,
                        );

            echo form_input($data); ?>

            <h5>العنوان</h5>
            <? $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'address',
                          'id'          => 'round_input',
                          'value'       => $address,
                          'size' => '70'
                        );

            echo form_input($data); ?>

            <h5>نبذة عني</h5>
            <? $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'about',
                          'id'          => 'round_input',
                          'value'       => $about,
                          'rows' => '3',
                          'cols' => '40',
                        );

            echo form_textarea($data); ?>

            <h5>الصورة الشخصية</h5>
            <img width="300" height="300" src="<? echo $profilepic; ?>" />

            <h5>إختيار صورة جديدة</h5>
            <? 
            $data = array(
                          'name'        => 'profilepic',
                          'id'          => 'profilepic',
                        );

            echo form_upload($data);
             ?>

            <div><input type="submit" value="احفظ التغييرات" /></div>

            </form>
 </div>
          <p>&nbsp; </p>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

will really appreciate it if someone tells me what I am doing that could lead to that chaos every now and then.

Regards,

Comment: Hard to tell you mate without testing, however based in the symptoms sounds like sometimes your where clause is not been added. That would be my guess. Is there any possibility you get nothing in your variable @username and then you end up with a NO-WHERE's CLAUSE?

Comment: am guessing not really. The where seems like it is getting executed anyhow...but what if the username is empty or null? would the where match everything?

Comment: Yes. If you haven't protected your code against sql injection. Someone could send $username  = ' 1 OR 1 = 1'. Done, everything got update. And can get worse: $username  = ' 1; DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME'.

Comment: @medina he is protected against sql injections. CI automatically escapes the values when using query builder.

Comment: Yes codeigniter escapes characters...I don't think I should be worried because of that.

Comment: what do you get from the debug?

Comment: Nothing really. The site has 25 users now...it works fine until one user does something with his profile, then all records in database change to those values. There is no error. I tried error logs and talking to host company (justhost) but nothing they could do or tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add code to check that username in the session exists.

If the session times out, codeigniter will return `FALSE`.

Querying MySQL on `username = false` will return all rows.

Comment: yeah, his check on if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
                    { should be higher up in the code;
actually, it should be in a controller which is extended

Comment: That check doesn't work, because it can come back as FALSE, which is the problem.

Comment: True! I added the code 2 days ago and things went well! Thanks for pointing that out :)